# mysql automatically cast strings to integer

Tags: php, mysql

I've just noticed that if I do a MySQL request like this one:

```
SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE id = 'asdf'
```

Then the string 'asdf' is casted to `0`. 
It means that I have a record with id `0` this will match. 
The format of the `id`  field is `int(8).`

What is the best way to proceed:

- I need to check (by PHP for example) that my value is numerical only?
- There is a MySQL way to do that?
- I must remove my record with id `0`? (bad)

Comment: The usual way to go is indeed to check the variable beforehand and to see whether it's numeric. (Many coding examples I've seen do a simple `(int)` cast though, which also results in `0`)

Comment: You should always check inputs, especially when executing commands against your database and even more so if part of the input is coming from an external user. This is just good practice (for example to avoid injection attacks). PHP has an isNumeric function http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: i wouldn't have a 0th record.

Comment: it depends if you mind catching characters in a integer field. mySQL will allow it, if you don't care that the string is not an integer, you can truncate the input record so it doesn't overflow your buffers. [LINK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: please reword title of question. I came here looking to know how to cast int as string, but it wasn't even answered. not user friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first sanitize your inputs via PHP.

```
$id = 'asdf';
if(is_numeric($id)){
    $query("SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE id = $id");
}else{
    die("ID is not numeric");
}
```

Or you can do:

```
    SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE id = 'asdf' AND 'asdf' REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
```

This would cause the regex to = false, causing no rows to return.

Comment: just another method to validate an int in php: `$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET | INPUT_POST, "varName", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);`

Comment: I would rather use **is_int($id)** instead, because **is_numeric($id)** would also go with "+0123.45e6". That of course depends on the Type of your Database Integer and its options.

Answer (score 4):

Just write your queries so that they don't use numeric fields as if they were textual ones.

If `id` is a numeric field, then your `where` clause can never be useful. Yes, it would be good if MySQL actively complained about it - but fundamentally you shouldn't be writing code which runs bad queries to start with.

How did that query enter your system? Is the `'asdf'` part direct user input? Can you use parameterized SQL instead?

If you're genuinely *intending* to query a numeric field, you should make sure that your input is numeric first. Convert the text to an integer in your calling code, *not* in the database.

Comment: @MarkByers: That doesn't mean you should be using non-integers in a query for integer input. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: I don't get your point when you say that if id is a numeric field, your where clause can never be useful

Answer (score 1):

Since pdo prepared statements binding with correct types will not raise any error (except if [mysql strict mode is enabled](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html)), your only choice is to ensure and control the types of your variables within your php to "correct" the permissivity of these languages.

[thanks to commentators]

Comment: In this case using prepared statements won't work, because the library will cast 'asdf' to 0, so it will return incorrect rows. The point about checking the type in php is totally correct though.