# mysql select where returns inexact match

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm seeing strange behavior when doing a `SELECT` on a table with a simple `WHERE` clause returns a record that does not match exactly.

my table has a column `id int(11)` as the primary key. to find a record with the id 5350, for example, the following 2 queries both return the record with the id 5350.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id="5350"
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id="5350abcd"
```

one thought I had was to remove the "" around 5350 but i get the same result. in codeigniter, i tried this:

```
$where = "id=$my_id";
$this->db->where($where);
```

why is this happening, and how do i fix it so the non-exact id does not find the record?

Comment: I must admit that it's unclear what your question is.. however your string values are being coerced to integers since column is defined as an integer. If you're wondering why both queries give the same results - it's because MySQL treats them as ints and pulls 5350 from both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second query the ID value is not an integer. You need to insure that the value is an integer before running the query, other wise it will cast the value to such.

Comment: thanks everyone for your answers. related: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983499/mysql-automaticaly-cast-strings-to-integer) solution is to check for int using `if(!is_int($my_id)) {...}` thx!

Answer (score 1):

It's resolving it to a number as the field is Int. if you used say just ="abcd" it would resolve to zero.

Oh, and you do not need the quotes for an int value

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it parses out the letters because it's of type int. It ignores everything that is alpha. Because it has the same ID with added numbers it resolves to the numbers before the letters.

```
5350 <-- INT
5350abcd <--- 'abcd' gets parsed out because it's not of INT type. 
You end up with 5350 without the abcd at the end.
```

had your field been of data type varchar it would have parsed all of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$where = array('id' => $my_id);
$this->db->where($where);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$where = "id=".((string)(int)$my_id === $my_id ? $my_id : 0);
$this->db->where($where);
```

But this solutions is still ugly, as you make query for nothing. You should check if `$my_id` is correct before making query.