# PHP: MySQL: Update is Updating More than One Row

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So I am trying to update update my 2 tables: Invoice and Order_Table. I want it to update the new quantity and the new price in each table but only for the specific OrderID. I came up with this:

```
$UpdateQuant = "UPDATE Order_Table SET Quantity = '$NewQuant' WHERE OrderID = '$OrderID' ";
$UpdateQuant = mysql_query($UpdateQuant);

$UpdatePrice = "UPDATE Order_Table SET TotalCost = '$NewPrice' WHERE OrderID = '$OrderID' ";
$UpdatePrice = mysql_query($UpdatePrice);


//Update Invoice Table
$UpdateQuant = "UPDATE Invoice SET Quantity = '$NewQuant' WHERE OrderID = '$OrderID' ";
$UpdateQuant = mysql_query($UpdateQuant);                   

$UpdatePrice = "UPDATE Invoice SET TotalCost = '$NewPrice' WHERE OrderID = '$OrderID' ";
$UpdatePrice = mysql_query($UpdatePrice);
```

However, when I execute this, it updates every single row. I don't see why this would even happen since I'm using WHERE `OrderID = '$OrderID'`

Comment: Echo out the SQL just before you execute it, maybe something isn't in the variables as you expect. Otherwise, it would have to be that each record updated has the same orderID.

Comment: Guessing OrderID is an integer in your database, you should leave out the single quotes around the `$OrderID`. As also explained on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983499/mysql-automaticaly-cast-strings-to-integer

Please also be advised that is it a sincere risk to use mysql_* functions and everyone will tell you to either use mysqli_* functions or pdo! Not only due to safety concerns, but also due to forward compatibility.

Comment: Can you run the following query and post the output? `SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE OrderID = '$OrderID'`?

Comment: I don't have enough information on the table schema and data in it to understand why such a statement would update all rows. On the surface, this appears OK.  I will say that you can likely make all these updates in a single query. `UPDATE Order_Table AS ot INNER JOIN Invoice AS i ON ot.OrderID = i.OrderID SET ot.quantity = ?, ot.TotalCost = ?, i.Quantity = ?, i.TotalCost = ? WHERE OrderID = ?` Where `?` would be replaced by your values. This would serve to make your update more atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Echo out the SQL just before you execute it, maybe something isn't in the variables as you expect. Otherwise, it would have to be that each record updated has the same orderID.

Also, as pointed out int he comments, only strings should be encapsulated by quotes, numeric types shouldn't have them:

You can also combine the queries you run into a single one like this:

```
$UpdateQuant = "UPDATE Order_Table SET Quantity = $NewQuant, TotalCost = $NewPrice WHERE OrderID = $OrderID ";
$UpdateQuant = mysql_query($UpdateQuant);
```

Which has combined the top two queries together and you can do likewise for the bottom two.

Comment: I'd suggest not using the same unsafe deprecated code.  While your code works, it still leaves the OP open to injection attacks.